# Every central-force field is integrable, right?

Tags: classical-mechanics, integrable-systems

In 3d, there are four independent first integrals, namely, the three components of the angular momentum, and the total energy.

So by the Liouville theorem, it is integrable, right?

Comment: You claim the total energy is an independent first integral, so do you want to assume your force is time independent as well as a central force?

Answer (score 2):

> by the Liouville theorem, it is integrable, right?

If you are asking whether every central force corresponds to an integrable system then the answer depends on whether you require the original version of Newton's first law or whether you mistakeningly think it is redundant and replace it with a different law.

If you don't require that objects at rest subject to no force stay at rest (as opposed to just instantaneously have zero acceleration as the second law requires) then you can have central forces where there is no Hamiltonian  flow to even be integrable. So questions about its integrability make no sense.

As an example let $r=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2+(z_1-z_2)^2}$ where $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ are the positions of the two particles. You can let $V(r)=-e^C(r-b)^a$ and then when you take the gradient you get a central force. And we get the third law. You can impose the second law as well. But unless you impose the first law as well, the motion can violate the first law if they start out a distance $b$ away, both initially at rest, and $0<a<1.$

Thus there isn't a unique solution to the equations of motion, hence no Hamiltonian flow, hence it doesn't make sense to say it is integrable or not integrable.

So it seems like just being a central force is in no way related to making there be vector fields with nice properties since it can't make there be vector fields at all.

**Let's assume you pick a system that does have unique solutions, and so does have a flow.** To use Liouville you need your integrals to be independent, and the three components of angular momentum are not independent at the origin.

My advice, if you want to use Liouville only consider systems where you have a flow. Remove bad places (where your integrals aren't independent or your flow isn't defined) such as the origin and remove anything that can flow to it or from it in finite time. Then try to use Liouville if you can actually meet the requirements (so time independent and have enough constants be independent). Then use other techniques for the parts of phase space you removed and for other problems where your flow just wasn't specified.

That is the historical approach and it's what other people do. For instance people usually do 1d first and then when they do 3d they simply don't care about 3d problems that stay in a line (because that is 1d and they already did 1d). So they ignore the region of phase space with zero angular momentum. You can too. Knowing what to ignore to get something that Liouville works for might be too hard in the sense that if tiu can do that then maybe you don't need Liouville.

Comment: I think you are too serious. We do physics, not mathematics. Your example is too contrived. I have just in mind a nice potential, like $r \exp(-r)$.

Comment: @kaiser Whatever makes your fields exist might or might not make them integrable. For the central force I listed you could pick different fields, which one do you want to show is integrable? The force isn't going to tell you the dynamics so you need to specify the dynamics. Do you expect them all to be integrable?

Comment: I have to specify the dynamics? I do not understand. There is only one dynamics, the newtonian dynamics, I think.

Comment: @kaiser And you can literally carve a hill to have that scalar potential as its height so its not a weird potential. And then there is no dynamics from F=ma alone you need additional laws, the first law for example. And yes you have to specify the dynamics, forces don't just give you dynamics just because they are central forces.

Comment: @kaiser I added three paragraphs about how to try to use Liouville and what to do to be able to use it. Its really just running down the hypotheses of the theorem, have a sympletic manifold, have a flow, have a bunch of functions, have them be independent and have them have zero Poisson bracket with each other (so be time independent to get energy), etc.

Comment: I am lost, possibly because I am not so good at mathematics. My background is just the classical mechanics course in university. I just want to talk about things in the sense of the standard course.